# Line search using secant method

Tags: convex-optimization, secant

To find the root of a strictly increasing function $f(x)$, given two test points $x_0, x_1$ such that $f(x_0) < 0$ and $f(x_1) > 1$, we can use the **secant method**, which has the following iteration scheme:

$$\begin{align}
x_2 &:= x_1 - f(x_1) \frac{ (x_1 - x_0)} {f(x_1) - f(x_0)} \\
x_0 &:= x_1\\
x_1 &:= x_2\\
\end{align}$$

Minimizing a (strictly) convex univariate function $f(x)$, means finding the zero of its (strictly) increasing derivative $g(x)$. A common way to do this **exact line search** is the [golden-section method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden-section_search). But since univariate derivatives are easy to compute numerically (choose an arbitrary small $h$ and compute $g = \frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h}$), **why not use the secant method instead?** The iteration scheme is

$$\begin{align}
x_2 &:= x_1 - g(x_1) \frac{ (x_1 - x_0)} {g(x_1) - g(x_0)} \\
x_0 &:= x_1\\
x_1 &:= x_2\\
\end{align}$$

and experimentation reveals that this converges relatively quickly toward a local minimum.

I ask because the line-search chapter in my textbook skips straight from the golden-section method to inexact line search techniques. The secant method doesn't come up until the chapter on quasi-Newton methods, where it amounts to a technique for estimating the multivariate Hessian.

I can see that the golden-section method has advantage of not needing to compute the gradients, but **is there any situation in which this secant-method exact line search might be preferable?**

Comment: From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secant_method): For example, if $f(x)$ is differentiable on that interval and there is a point where $f'=0$ on the interval, then the algorithm may not converge. This is true for functions like $f(x) = \cosh x - 2$ where I chose $x_0 = --1$, $x_1 = 1.5$.

Comment: Are there any examples of strictly increasing functions where the secant method fails to converge? If not, then by analogy the secant method could be used for line search if we assume *strict* convexity.

Comment: Anyhow, I just tried the secant method on your example (assuming you meant $x_0 = -1$) and it converged to $x^* = 1.3169579$ in about 7 iterations. Moreover, the function $\cosh x - 2$ function is not monotonic, so it isn't relevant to convex line search.